# unable to load data from local json file via angularJS inside jquery mobile app

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, jquery-mobile

Im trying to load some data from a local json file and put it inside a jquery mobile `listview` using angularJS. Im having a hard time to understand how do I combine the `ng-repeat` with the `data-role="listview"`.
For the fiddle example i used an online hosted json file from filltext.com.

i updated the code according to Danyu's suggestion, but it still doesnt work. Now all the usernames appear in ONE li element, instead of one username in one li element.

fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/hh8hS/

html code:

```
<div data-role="page" id="scientists" ng-app="test">
    <div data-role="header"><h3>jquery mobile + json call test</h3></div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <div ng-controller="controller">
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-filter="true">
                <li ng-repeat="item in itemSet">{{item.username}}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS code:

```
var data1= [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "email": "RWahl@vitae.net",
        "username": "NCollier",
        "password": "XIsyw"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "email": "AKahlig@eget.net",
        "username": "NDerucher",
        "password": "f687l"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "email": "KKirkley@sagittis.com",
        "username": "DBario",
        "password": "Vl7ND"
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "email": "NMcgarity@magna.com",
        "username": "LOng",
        "password": "JeTnK"
    }
    ];

var myApp=angular.module("test",[]);

myApp.controller("controller", function($scope,$http){
   $http.get("data1").success(function(data){
      $scope.itemSet=data;
   });
});
```

EDIT:
apparently the code works with the little change Danyu suggested, it was a local problem on my PC.

Comment: If no data is loaded and displayed, try URL in the browser see if there is any data being returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-repeat on the `<li>` element instead of the parent `<ul>`:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in scientists">
   {{item.username}}
</li>
```

Comment: i inserted the ng-repeat inside the li element, and now all the usernames are printed inside one li element. what else am i missing?

Comment: Could you check the structure of the returned data? If the data is an array, like data=[{username:...},{username:...}], it should work. But if it is an object that has an array, like data={[...]}, all names will be built into a single li.

Comment: the structure of the data is [{"id": 1,"username": "a"},{...}]